# How to Populate a Drop-down field in WP

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form form on my WP site and I recently changed a free text field into a drop down field.
The website is a store which hold several categories of goods and I want my drop-down to show the user all the possible categories he can choose from.
Please assist in how to "pull" the categories into the drop-down list.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using some filters of gravity form, code is following

```
// Here 1 is form id
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_category' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_category' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_category' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_category' );
function populate_category( $form ) {

   foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

       if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-category' ) === false ) {
        continue;
    }

   // Get category list
    $categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
  ) );

      $choices = array();

      foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $choices[] = array( 'text' => $category->name, 'value' => $category->name );
    }


    $field->placeholder = 'Select a Category';
    $field->choices = $choices;

  }

  return $form;
}
```

This is working perfectly its tested code.